# Laravel Eloquent JOIN over multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble with a JOIN over 2 tables. One of them isn't associated directly with the Eloquent model 'Message'.

My Tables:

```
videos
-- id
-- file

messages
-- m_id
-- m_type
-- m_video

videos_languages
-- video_id
-- language_id
```

I have the following models:

```
User.php  
Video.php  
Message.php
```

Video.php has following relation:

```
public function languages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language','videos_languages','video_id','language_id')->withPivot('titel','vl_id');
}
```

Message.php

```
public function messageVideos()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Video','m_video','id');
}

public function messageUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Visitor','m_from','v_id');
}
```

In my main script, I do the following command:

```
$message = new Message();
$message->where('m_to','=',12345)->with('messageVideos','messageUser')->first()
```

So I get the data of Message with the associated tables "Videos" and "User".

My problem now: I also need videos_languages in this command, and it is not associated with the Message model.

Is it possible, to include it within the top command and use the languages() relation from the Video model?

Comment: You can nest models in with, with a dot:
->with('messageVideos.languages','messageUser')->first();

Does this work?

Comment: Hi Björn, thank you, that works. But is it possible, to add a where condition for language in the command? Now I got all languages associated with the video, but in one mthod I only want the language with the id 1.

Comment: I believe now you will need whereHas http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations , you can nest them.

Comment: Nesting it doesn't work, it says, messageVideos.languages is undefined: @user2094178 `$message->where('m_to','=',12345)->with('messageVideos.languages','messageUser')->whereHas('messageVideos.languages',function($q) { $q->where('id','=','1'); })->first()`

Comment: `whereHas` doesn't support `messageVideos.languages`, `languages`must have a `whereHas` of its own and be nested within the `whereHas` of `messageVideos`.

Comment: @user2094178 - so now I got this one here: 

`$message->where('m_to','=',12345)->with('messageVideos.languages','messageUser')->whereHas('messageVideos',function($q) { $q->whereHas('languages',function($d) { $d->where('id','=',2); }); })->first()`  

Problem now: I still get all languages in my results, I only want the language with id 2.

Comment: It should be working, please try removing the `with()` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need "whereHas", but "Eager Load Constraints".
This is found under [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) in the laravel docs.

For Example:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}))->get();
```

You however need to nest it and load more relations.

So it's like this:

```
$message = Message::where('m_to','=',12345)
->with(array('messageVideos.languages' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('language_id', '=', 2);
},
'messageUser'))->first();
```